# Super-Operator In Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-custom-resources, operator-sdk

I need to automate the provisioning of a complex application in Kubernetes. It's a complex, multi-step process that involves provisioning of some cluster-wide resources and some app-specific resources. The cluster-wide resources are:

- Istio
- A few Operators (Cert Manager, Prometheus Operator, Postgres Operator, among others)

Then I want to create an application (let's call it `Foo`) which leverages Istio and the aforementioned operators. It will create statefulsets, services, Certificates, a Postgres database, Istio gateways, Prometheus PodMonitors, etc.

There will be multiple `Foo`'s created, each configured differently (since the Kubernetes cluster will be used to provide `Foo` applications as a multi-tenant service).

What's the idiomatic way to do this? I think I should write a `Foo` controller which assumes that Istio and the other operators (prometheus, cert-manager, postgres, etc) already exist.

Is it possible to write a meta `ClusterOfFoos` operator that installs Istio, installs the required operators, and then installs the `Foo` controller?

If so, how does one go about provisioning operators (normally installed through Helm) from within a controller?

So far I have looked into using helm to do this, but there are too many dependencies and Helm just tends to create all resources at once, which makes some things fail (eg. when a deployment refers to a Secret that hasn't yet been created by cert-manager).

Comment: Can you consider using Helm with ArgoCD?

Comment: Hadn't heard of ArgoCD. It looks promising, thank you!

Comment: Take a look at ArgoCD Sync Waves: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/sync-waves

Comment: It is definitely possible to write an operator that invokes other operators; in core Kubernetes, a Deployment controller creates ReplicaSets, and a separate ReplicaSet controller creates Pods.  It's a matter of local experience whether an operator (presumably in Go) or a domain-specific tool (Helm, Helmfile) is a better match for your needs.

Comment: I don't see a real question here. "Can you do it? Yes, you can".

Comment: @DavidMaze you're correct; the problem though is that I don't need to just invoke other operators; I need to create CRD's. It seems like the docs for the Op SDK discourage this: "An Operator shouldn’t deploy or manage other operators (such patterns are known as meta or super operators or include CRDs in its Operands)."

Answer (score 1):

The [Operator Lifecycle Manager](https://olm.operatorframework.io/docs/getting-started/) is really well suited for the task.

When you create operator `Foo`, you can package it in the OLM way by creating a bundle which contains the [ClusterServiceVersion](https://olm.operatorframework.io/docs/tasks/creating-operator-manifests/#writing-your-operator-manifests) needed to inform OLM of dependencies that need to be resolved before install and during upgrades. These can just be a list of APIs you need - and OLM will find and install the set of latest versions of the operators that own each API.

All your dependencies are operators available in the [Operatorhub.io Catalog](https://operatorhub.io/) so they are available for install and dependency resolution as soon as you install OLM.

You can also configure certain dependencies by including these objects in the bundle itself. According to [the docs](https://olm.operatorframework.io/docs/tasks/creating-operator-manifests/#packaging-additional-objects-alongside-an-operator), the following objects are supported as of the time of this post:

```
Secret
ClusterRole
ClusterRoleBinding
ConfigMap
ServiceAccount
Service
Role
RoleBinding
PrometheusRule
ServiceMonitor
PodDisruptionBudget
PriorityClasse
VerticalPodAutoscaler
ConsoleYAMLSample
ConsoleQuickStart
ConsoleCLIDownload
ConsoleLink
```

The [Operator SDK](https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/olm-integration/) can help you with bootstrapping the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

By using GitOps workflow you can automate  complex applications in Kubernetes.

- You need to define cluster-wide resources and application specific resources in a YAML file.
- By using GitOps tools you can continuously deploy kubernetes resources and they will automatically deploy the changes in the cluster.
- Use Helm chart to install Istio and make sure dependencies in the Helm chart are created in order.
- You can create a custom controller by FOO where it can read configuration of YAML files.
- Use kubernetes CRDs to define configuration of each FOO; they will allow you to create custom resources which are specific for each application.
- By using Helm; it will read the configuration from the CRD and generate correct YAML values.

The above described approach will allow you to create multiple FOO applications with different configurations and ensure that the required resources are installed in correct order.

You can check this article from codefresh regarding [GitOps Workflow](https://codefresh.io/learn/gitops/gitops-workflow-vs-traditional-workflow-what-is-the-difference/) and official [kubernetes page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/).
You can also check [Working with Multiple Applications and Environments](https://www.gitops.tech/#working-with-multiple-applications-and-environments) and how [Argo CD](https://www.gitops.tech/#working-with-multiple-applications-and-environments) is useful for this scenario.